# Authorization_IdentityNotFound on Microsoft Graph API request first time,

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

It is now 2021, but I meet this issue again....

When calling the `/users` MS Graph API, it says:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_IdentityNotFound",
        "message": "The identity of the calling application could not be established.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "b2d9ec62-0b65-44eb-9e0f-4aec52b45750",
            "date": "2021-01-22T10:19:48"
        }
    }
}
```

I use the 'client credentials' flow, and I've already configured to get the admin consent to get the tenant id. Then use it to call `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token` to get token.

And I configured the permissions/scopes as:

```
- Directory.Read.All
- User.Read.All
- Calendars.ReadWrite
```

Or even:

```
- Directory.Read.All
- Calendars.ReadWrite
```

The strange thing is that this error only happens with the token got by authorizing the app with a global admin account first time. It will work if use a second token gets back after a few seconds. And by comparing the two tokens, I found the differences are the not working one doesn't have 'roles: string[]` value in the JWT, while the working one has (see attached images).

[token not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eeb8t.png)
[token working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4KCU.png)

Anyone can help me out?
It's very appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: The reason behind this could be that if you just updated the roles and tried to call /token endpoint without any delay, you would see this scenario. It may take few seconds to update its permissions.

Comment: When I use client credentials flow to generate access token, I always set scope as 'h t t p s://graph.microsoft.com/.default', try it?

Comment: @Tiny-wa I've set it as is already :(

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity But I've configured the permissions already in the Azure Portal. Would it be possible there are some other permissions missed in the list of I pre-configured? So the Azure backend goes to configure it dynamically when my app's customer does the consent the first time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error is not that you lack permissions, it is caused by the delay.

Your idea is correct. The reason why your first token call is unsuccessful is the lack of `roles` claim in the token, which means that the permissions are not injected into the first token. When you grant **admin consent** to the application, it will be delayed. If you get the token right now, it may cause the token to lack permissions. So, please wait a few minutes after you grant the admin consent before trying to obtain the token.

Comment: Thanks! We're handling this by delay then retry steps now.